# Warning: Failed context type: The context `store.isRequired` is marked as required in `Routing`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having an issue with react-redux Provider:
I moved our router out of our index.js to a routing.js file. I used a Provider to give my Routing component knowledge of the store but I'm getting a strange warning before the execution reaches the render method :

`` Warning: Failed context type: The context `store.isRequired` is marked as required in `Routing`, but its value is `undefined`. ``

This happens even if I get rid of the `.isRequired` in `Routing.contextTypes`. Moreover if I put a debugger statement at the beginning of the render function, it appears that `this.context`isn't undefined and my app is working like a charm. I'm wondering if I did something wrong or if it could possibly be a bug of react-redux Provider or something.

Here is my code:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { setLanguage } from 'redux-i18n';
import I18n from 'redux-i18n/immutable';

import configureStore from './store/configure_store';
import { Routing } from './routing';
import translations from './translations';

import '../scss/index.scss';

const store = configureStore();

store.dispatch(setLanguage(navigator.language));

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={ store }>
        <I18n translations={ translations }>
            <Routing />
        </I18n>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**routing.js (simplified for reading purpose)**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRedirect, IndexRoute, Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import AppContainer from './components/App/App';
import Base from './components/Root/Base';
import BaseInProject from './components/App/BaseInProject';
import { ProjectListContainer } from './components/App/Projects/ProjectsList';

export class Routing extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { store } = this.context;

        const beforeAppRouteEnter = (nextState, replace, callback) => {
            // This function needs to store.dispatch some stuff
        };

        // Some other router functions

        const routes = (
            <Route path='/' component={ Base }>

                <Route component={ AppContainer } onEnter={ beforeAppRouteEnter }>
                    <IndexRoute component={ ProjectListContainer } />

                         // Some other routes

                        <IndexRedirect to='media' />
                    </Route>
                </Route>
            </Route>
        );

        return (
            <Router history={ browserHistory }>{ routes }</Router>
        );
    }
}
Routing.contextTypes = {
    store: React.PropTypes.shape(React.PropTypes.any)
};
```

Thanks!